# How to avoid Internet Explorer's "Webpage has expired" when using the back button with an app inside a Page Tab?

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

I've built a Facebook canvas app, which has been added as a Page Tab. In Internet Explorer, when I click a link from the homepage of the page tab to another page, and then press the browser back button, I get a message from IE:

> Webpage has expired
>   Most likely cause: The local copy of this webpage is out of date, and the website requires that you download it again.

If I press refresh then the page displays correctly, but I'd like to be avoid this extra step.

Here's the link to the app:
https://www.facebook.com/FindAnyFilm/app_324458010982848

Click on one of the latest entries, then press the browser back button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could have to do with the caching headers your server sends,

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma:        no-cache
```

Try changing these and see if the problem persists; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654296/1427878 for further info on IE & caching behavior.