# How to avoid "Web page has expired" in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cache-control

I have a page with a form.
When I post the form, then I click the *previous button* in IE, I have an error : "**The web page has expired**"

As I seen it [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403589/how-to-avoid-internet-explorers-webpage-has-expired-when-using-the-back-butto), I tried :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Now, I don't have the expired message anymore, but the **form just auto revalidate**. When I click the previous button, I see I go back to my form page, then I just return to the result page.

Did I do something wrong? I don't understand much in `Cache-Control` and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just because of IE caching version. I also found this issue and find some relevant article on this. 
You can take a look on this - 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183763

Comment: The MS support link is broken.