# Getting Webpage has expired error when click on browser back navigation button

Tags: browser, browser-cache

I have an issue in my project like if I click on browser back navigation button it is showing error page saying **Webpage has expired**

If I refresh the page, page will be displayed but the data is lost.

This issue is there with IE only not with  Firefox and chrome. In these two browsers I am getting the page correctly.

Is there any way to solve this so that I can get the previous page?

Comment: Is the previous page accessed with a POST request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775063/asp-net-browser-shows-web-page-has-expired-for-back-button-after-a-post-back

Answer (score 1):

This may because of caching headers your server sends,

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma:        no-cache
```

Read this [Using back button: IE and Safari not reading from cache whereas Firefox and Chrome do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652711/using-back-button-ie-and-safari-not-reading-from-cache-whereas-firefox-and-chro/6654296#6654296)

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thanks for the reply. But no where we were setting those header parameters which you mentioned.

Comment: I solved this by disabling menu bar of the browser and backspace buttons default event function